# MFC control and value variables

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

in Microsoft Foundation Class Library   ,what is the difference value variables and control variables which are attached to  graphic components ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're asking about the way you attach variables to graphic controls in the Dialog Editor:

The "value" variables relate to the content of the control and the "control" variables relate to the control itself.

For example, for a `CEdit` control, the content variable might be a `CString` or an `int` etc., which is a variable that may contain the content that the user has entered into the control (or the content you may wish to display), while the control variable will be a `CEdit` instance that you can use to affect the control itself. For example to enable/disable input.

**Note** - please also read comments by @Vlad Feinstein, which correctly indicate that there is more to the dialog exchange mechanism than is encapsulated in this answer. My answer *only* clarifies the difference between the two types of variable mapping available from the dialog editor, which is what was originally asked. This answer is *not* (and will never be!) a tutorial on how to create and use dialogs in MFC.

Comment: BTW you can have a control variable _and_ a value variable for the _same_ control.

Comment: @MichaelWalz That's correct. It would be pretty stupid to only allow one, but it's actually not that obvious from the dialog editor. Good to point it out specifically.

Comment: Re: "variable that contains the content that the user has entered into the control" - this needs to be clarified: it doesn't happen automagically, user needs to call UpdateData(TRUE/FALSE); to move the content between the control and that variable,

Comment: @VladFeinstein Correct, but I'm trying to answer the question *as asked*, without launching into a tutorial about the DDX exchange mechanism!

Comment: @Roger Rowland - I would have no comments if your answer had `"variable that sometimes contains..."` or `"variable that may contain..."` :)

Comment: Just for newbies like me: Using `UpdateData(TRUE or FALSE)` makes life easier because if we don't use it, we should use functions such as `GetDlgItemText(...)` and `SetDlgItemText(...)` for *every* get/set data. Just calling UpdateData once for each TRUE/FALSE takes care of it.

Comment: Oh, one question. It seems like 'control' variables can do everything that 'value' variables can do (for example using set/get method). Correct?